# Problemas con una lista usando CSS

Tags: css

Esta Imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es de una lista que estoy haciendo pero quiero que quede así[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y este es mi codigo CSS y HTML:

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
counter-reset:li;
padding:10px;
left:-8px;
width:100%;
}
li{ /* Styles of each element */
width:100%;
position:relative;
left:0;
margin:0 0 1px 12px;
padding:4px 5px;
}
ul li:before{
content: counter(li);
counter-increment: li;
position: absolute; 
left: -30px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -13px;
background: #8E8E8E; /* background color of the numbers */
height: 1.9em;
width: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
}
ul li:after{
position: absolute;
content: '';
left: -2px;
margin-top: -.7em; 
top: 50%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
border-left:10px solid #8E8E8E; /* background color of the right arrow*/
}
ul li a{
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;   
font-size:15px;
}
ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: .4em .4em .4em .8em;
*padding: .4em;
margin: .5em 0 .5em 0.4em;
background: #ddd;
transition: all .3s ease-out;
text-decoration:none;
transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
ul li:hover{
background: #eee; /* Background color on mouseover */
}   
ul li a:hover{
color:#444; /* Link color on mouseover */
margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo-frame">
<ul id="lista1" class="gallery">
 <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
<ul id="lista2">
 <li>Item5</li>
    <li>Item6</li>
    <li>Item7</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Te sugiero incluir también tu HTML, saludos

Comment: @ReinosRic deberias incluir el codigo HTML + codigo funcional

Comment: puedes usar flex, algo asi: ul{ display:flex; }

Comment: como ya te han sugerido, sin el html no podemos ayudarte

Comment: Hola, acabo de agregar mi HTML, saludos

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que simplemente se acomode una al lado de la otra?

Comment: Si, como la segunda imagen que tengo de ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola a todos: resulta que el problema radicaba en el "width" ya que lo que ponía como porcentaje (%) realmente lo quería como **px**.

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la propiedad `flex` que sugirió @Elberth, nada más habría que agregar este pedazo de código:

```
#demo-frame{
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;  //Sólo para acortarlo
}
```

```css
/*Flexbox*/
#demo-frame{
 display: flex;
 width: 50%; 
} 
  
  ul{
list-style:none;
counter-reset:li;
padding:10px;
left:-8px;
width:100%;
}
li{ /* Styles of each element */
width:100%;
position:relative;
left:0;
margin:0 0 1px 12px;
padding:4px 5px;
}
ul li:before{
content: counter(li);
counter-increment: li;
position: absolute; 
left: -30px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -13px;
background: #8E8E8E; /* background color of the numbers */
height: 1.9em;
width: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
}
ul li:after{
position: absolute;
content: '';
left: -2px;
margin-top: -.7em; 
top: 50%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
border-left:10px solid #8E8E8E; /* background color of the right arrow*/
}
ul li a{
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;   
font-size:15px;
}
ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: .4em .4em .4em .8em;
*padding: .4em;
margin: .5em 0 .5em 0.4em;
background: #ddd;
transition: all .3s ease-out;
text-decoration:none;
transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
ul li:hover{
background: #eee; /* Background color on mouseover */
}   
ul li a:hover{
color:#444; /* Link color on mouseover */
margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo-frame">
 <ul id="lista1" class="gallery">
  <li>Item1</li>
     <li>Item2</li>
     <li>Item3</li>
     <li>Item4</li>
 </ul>
 <ul id="lista2">
  <li>Item5</li>
     <li>Item6</li>
     <li>Item7</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa es wrappear ambos listados en `divs` con `display:inline-block`.

De esta manera ambos listados se van a colocar en la misma linea.

[CSS - Inline-block](http://es.learnlayout.com/inline-block.html)

Luego puedes asignarle `vertical-align:top;` a ambas `divs` para que los listados esten alineados desde el primer elemento.

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
counter-reset:li;
padding:10px;
left:-8px;
width:100%;
}
li{ /* Styles of each element */
width:100%;
position:relative;
left:0;
margin:0 0 1px 12px;
padding:4px 5px;
}
ul li:before{
content: counter(li);
counter-increment: li;
position: absolute; 
left: -30px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -13px;
background: #8E8E8E; /* background color of the numbers */
height: 1.9em;
width: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
}
ul li:after{
position: absolute;
content: '';
left: -2px;
margin-top: -.7em; 
top: 50%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
border-left:10px solid #8E8E8E; /* background color of the right arrow*/
}
ul li a{
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;   
font-size:15px;
}
ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: .4em .4em .4em .8em;
*padding: .4em;
margin: .5em 0 .5em 0.4em;
background: #ddd;
transition: all .3s ease-out;
text-decoration:none;
transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
ul li:hover{
background: #eee; /* Background color on mouseover */
}   
ul li a:hover{
color:#444; /* Link color on mouseover */
margin-left:3px;
}

.inline-block-div{
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo-frame">
  <div class="inline-block-div">
    <ul id="lista1" class="gallery">
      <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <li>Item3</li>
        <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block-div">
      <ul id="lista2">
        <li>Item5</li>
          <li>Item6</li>
          <li>Item7</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```